# Method that returns integers that are greater than a selected integer in an array

Tags: java, arrays, search, methods

Here is what I have so far and it works for some test cases. The method works well with some arrays but not others. I am getting lost as to where the issue is. Description of method is in the comments above method.

```
/**
    * Return an array of all the elements of a that are greater than val.
    * If a contains no elements greater than val, this method returns an
    * array of zero length.
    *
    * @param a the array to be searched
    * @param val the reference value
    * @return the elements a[i] such that a[i] > val
    *
    */
   public static int[] greater(int[] a, int val) {
      if (a == null || a.length == 0) {

         throw new IllegalArgumentException();         
      }

      int x = 0;

      int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);

      Arrays.sort(copy);

      int nearest = copy[0];   
      for (int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {

         if (Math.abs(nearest - val) > Math.abs(copy[i] - val)) {
            nearest = copy[i]; 
            x = i; 

         }   

      }
      if ((x + 1) >= copy.length) {
         int[] badAnswer = new int[0];
         return badAnswer;
      }
      else { 
         int[] answer = new int[(copy.length - 1) - x];
         int index = 0;
         while (index < answer.length) {

            answer[index] = copy[x + (index + 1)];

            index++; 

         }
         return answer;
      }

   }
```

This works for this test using JUnit:

```
int a[] = {17,14,3,10,5,1,25};
@Test public void greaterTest() {
      int d[] = Selector.greater(a, 5);
      int p[] = {10, 14, 17, 25};
      Assert.assertArrayEquals(d, p);

   }
```

but not for this one:

```
int z[] = {-5,-2,0,4,8,15,50};

@Test public void greaterTest2() {
   int d[] = Selector.greater(z, -99);
   int p[] = {-5,-2,0,4,8,15,50};
   Assert.assertArrayEquals(d, p);
```

also not for repeating integers that are all less than val:

```
int z[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    @Test public void greaterTest2() {
       int d[] = Selector.greater(z, 51);
       int p[] = {};
       Assert.assertArrayEquals(d, p);
    }
```

Any ideas on how to fix these gaps in my method?

Comment: Your algo seems over-complicated: once the array is sorted, loop until you find an item > val and arraycopy whatever is at or after that index...

Comment: I am very new to java and am taking classes for it as we speak. Is there any way you could elaborate on your methodology?

Comment: @assylias is correct, is not java dependent what he say .. when you have you arrray sorted , just loop the array sorted and then return all the values until an item > val

Comment: I believe i understand you now. How would i make an exception for a situation in which there are no greater values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static int[] greater(int[] a, int val)
{
    int[] greater = new int[a.length];
    int greaterNumber = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < greater.length; i++)
        if (a[i] > val)
            greater[greaterNumber++] = a[i];

    return Arrays.copyOf(greater, greaterNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the JDK, needing just two lines:

```
public static int[] greater(int[] a, int val) {
    Arrays.sort(a);
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(a, Math.abs(Arrays.binarySearch(a, val) + 1), a.length;
}
```

I have omitted parameter checking etc to emphasise the elegance and simplicity of this approach.

See a [live demo](http://ideone.com/fFZCnZ) on ideone.

Answer (score 1):

I see I am not the first answer, but mine's annotated:

```
private static int[] greater(int[] array, int v) {
    // create space for the potential values greater than 'v'
    int[] potentials = new int[array.length];
    // an 'insertion point' in to the potentials array.
    int ip = 0;
    for (int a : array) {
        // for each value in the input array....
        if (a > v) {
            // if it is greater than 'v', add it to the potentials
            // and increment the ip insertion point.
            potentials[ip++] = a;
        }
    }
    // return the valid values from the potentials
    return Arrays.copyOf(potentials, ip);
}
```